# REGEX:\b\p[A-Z]+\b

Tags: regex

This one is a bit odd.

I thought that this bit of REGEX ->>

```
\b\p[A-Z]+\b
```

would capture ALL UPPERCASE text.

It does.

It also captures all uppercase SINGLE characters too!!

Huh ?

So an "A" gets caught in this as well..it shouldn't. How do I correct for this ???

The REGEX is clearly off. I either need to add a negative look ahead (which I've never done before) OR I need to add a nested conditional to handle this issue, again way beyond my current skill set.

Comment: What is regex flavor?

Comment: What are your requirements for capturing uppercase text? The text has to be greater than a certain length?

Comment: requirements ? capture all WORDS in a given text. But not single characters....

Like "I hope you ARE having A NICE day".

I want the regex to capture the "ARE" & "NICE" but not the "I" or "A".

Comment: `I` and `A` ARE words, so is `an` and `the`. You have to set capture requirements at some length if you do not want `I` or `A`

Comment: @anubhava I'm using TEXTSOAP for the Mac which employs ICU Regex, I think.

Comment: It works the way you observe because `+` means *one or more*. No 'huh' needed; both "I" and "A" consist of one or more uppercase characters. You may want to try with `{2,}` instead of the simple `+` (it depends on your language if this works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a regex like this:

```
/[A-Z]{2,}/
```

Which matches as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/iC4jQ9/1).

A good explanation is given at the link. However, `[A-Z]` captures all uppercase letters, and `{2,}` adds the constraint of '2 or more' ('from 2 up to infinity' to be honest).

*Update*: As mentioned in the comments and showed in the answer below, I forgot to mention the `\b` constraint in order to match words only and not different parts of words. Please compare [this](https://regex101.com/r/hX9rG0/2) and [this](https://regex101.com/r/hX9rG0/1).

Comment: what??? this thing that matches `UPPERlowerUPPER` 2 times is the RIGHT answer to your question? I give up :(

Comment: @Aprillion: You're definitely correct. For sure, you need to add the 'word boundary position' constraint by using `\b` both at the end and at the beginning. Forgot to mention that :/

Answer (score 6):

If your regex engine supports [{min,max} quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit), use: `\b[A-Z]{2,}\b`

otherwise you can match 2 or more characters like: `\b[A-Z][A-Z]+\b`